# How to get rid of error

Tags: java, virtualization, error-handling

I am using m2 macbook with UTM virtualization (ubuntu linux OS) i am installing hadoop But there's only one error
ERROR: JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjak-amd64 does not exist.

Comment: This problem was most likely been caused by a typo. This is not enough for a full answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change `java-11-openjak-amd64` so that instead of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjak-amd64` it should be `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64`